# Push View Controller, Black Screen

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm pushing to a new view controller and passing some data to it. When I run the application I can press the button and push to a new view but the screen is completely black. Any help is appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {

    NSString *firstField = self.field.text;
    NSString *secondField = self.field2.text;

    self.resultsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstField, secondField, nil];

    NSUInteger randomResult = arc4random_uniform(self.resultsArray.count);
    self.label.text = [self.resultsArray objectAtIndex:randomResult];

    ImagesViewController *ivc = [[ImagesViewController alloc] init];
    ivc.label = self.label.text;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: what is the context of this ? are you allocating the view controller from storyboard? a xib file? no thing at all just randomly?

Answer (score 51):

When you're using a storyboard, and you want to push a view controller in code (rather than with a segue), you need to give the controller an identifier, and create it like this:

```
    ImagesViewController *ivc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    ivc.label = self.label.text;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];
```

Comment: The storyboard object can be retrieved with `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];` where "Main" is the storyboard's filename without the extension (so could also be "Main_iPhone" or "Main_iPad").

Comment: @BrianWhite, true, but if the calling controller is in the same storyboard as the new controller, it's shorter to just use self.storyboard.

Comment: Sure.  I was trying to access it from the AppDelegate which did not have that property and so had to do some more searching.  I figured I'd append what I learned so others might avoid the extra work if they were trying to do the same.

Comment: Anyone that tried this and had the "Expected ']'" warning, put a ':'before "@MyIdentifier", so it will stay like this: instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"

Comment: @RodrigoVenancio, thanks for catching that typo. I've corrected the post.

Comment: @rdelmar And thank you for your answer, it solved my problem! I tried to edit your answer but stackoverflow didn't allow me.

Answer (score 2):

The view controller you are pushing is not having any frame dimension set.It is always recommended to call designated init for objects. For view controllers, designated init method is

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
```

if you have a xib assign it like

```
ImagesViewController *ivc = [[ImagesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:<your xib> bundle:[NSBundle mainbundle];
```

if you are using custom view, assign a frame dimension and add it as subview

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2

In my case, I had made changes in the storyboard and made it a TabBarController and accordingly changed the class of the controller from UIViewController to UITabBarController. After some tweaking, this change wasn't favourable and I un did all the changes and got a black screen then because I had forgotten to change the class of the controller. I changed it back to UIViewController and it started working again.

So check if you have made the same mistake. The black screen came because the storyboard had a class(UIView/UITabBar/UITableView Controller)  but that wasnt the same in code.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you have somehow got an incorrect connection between one of the subviews in the storyboard to the controller's view. Check the Referencing Outlets are correct in each of your subviews.

Answer (score 1):

I got a good one:

Make sure you are implementing the right Super class, delegate, etc.. in the top part of the viewController you are trying to present. i.e.

I wasn't using/implementing UINavigationController at all

```
class TMDetailBlogViewController: UINavigationController {
  //code goes here
}
```

After

```
class TMDetailBlogViewController: UIViewController {
  //code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you transition to another view controller by calling:

```
initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

on your custom UIViewController.

If you're not using a xib file, then what you're doing may be fine. Are you dynamically creating your UI elements within the constructor of your ImagesViewController?

Comment: I don't have a xib. I'm creating the UI elements from the storyboard.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to make use of this method to handle your view transition: - (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender

Answer (score 0):

I was trying without using storyboard, and its just that the default screen it uses is in black color. I changed the background color to white and it worked.

Pushed the controller this way-

NextController *nextController = [[NextController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];

In NextController-

```
(void)viewDidLoad{
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

}