# pushViewController results in black screen if animated iOS 7 only

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewanimation

We have the following code (in the "signonSuccessful" method of our "SignonViewController"):

```
WelcomeViewController *welcomeScreen = [[WelcomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WelcomeViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:welcomeScreen animated:YES];
[welcomeScreen release];
```

When we do this, *on iOS 7 only*, the result is a black screen.  But placing stops in WelcomeViewController we find that `init`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, et al, are all hit.  In fact, `shouldRotateToInterfaceRotation` is hit if we rotate the device.  It's just that the screen is totally black, and it appears that button pushes are not detected.

However, if we say `animated:NO`, the screen appears & functions just fine.  And it's fine with `animated:YES` on iOS 6.x.

This is an iPad-only app.  "Legacy" app being 7-ified, no storyboards.  The above code is executing in the main thread.  And (obviously from the `release` above) this is manual reference counting.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does welcomeScreen have a valid frame dimension (non CGRectZero)?

Comment: The welcome screen is described by a valid XIB.

Comment: (I'm trying to remember how we resolved this.  I think we may have simply disabled animation for iOS 7.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using storyboards? If so, this should help:

[PushViewController Leads To Black Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929039/pushviewcontroller-leads-to-black-screen)

Also this:

[Push View Controller, Black Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861940/push-view-controller-black-screen)

Comment: No storyboards.  This is something of a "legacy" app.