# Scroll View onTap Gesture with Navigation Controller Gets a Black view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Im testing the onTap Gesture with `ScrollView` and found out it was pretty straight forward to implement, what i'm having trouble is with the next step which is Pushing the view the next `ViewController`, it generates a Black screen with the `navigation bar` or generates the screen but when i touch the back button it generates this screen again.

My viewdidload is the following:

```
(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1500)];
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];

UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTap)];
gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[scroller addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

}

and the onTap is

```
-(void)onTap{
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];}`

Comment: are you using storyboard ? Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929039/pushviewcontroller-leads-to-black-screen and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861940/push-view-controller-black-screen

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot for this problem

Comment: Thank you very much i solved it by using this: SegundoViewController *viewController = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondview"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];