# Push a new viewController (without segue) gives me a black screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, push

I want to start a new viewController without using a button and without using navigationController.
I try this in code in my Class1:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying");

    Tag1U2ViewController* controller = [[Tag1U2ViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

}
```

After the audio has finished it should call my Class2, that has only the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"View loaded");
}
```

My console-output:

```
Jul 29 15:00:37 bastis-air HelloUniverse[541] <Warning>: audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying
Jul 29 15:00:37 bastis-air HelloUniverse[541] <Warning>: View loaded
```

My problem now is, that the new screen is completely black. 
I've only change the class of the new ViewController in the storyboard.

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStortBoardName" bundle:nil];
    Tag1U2ViewController *controller = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyBoardId"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

Comment: check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861940/push-view-controller-black-screen

Comment: let me know what is the status....

Comment: @Spynet where should I put this code class1 or class2?

Comment: all scenes are in one story board or different

Comment: yes one storyboard. I don't understand the first line UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStortBoardName" bundle:nil];   What ist myStoryBoardName?

Comment: if your scenes are in the different storyboard then use the above code

Comment: No, I've only the Main.storyboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58251/discussion-between-spynet-and-user3433232).

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I having set a storyboardId with the name "uebung2" now it works fine:
My new code:

```
Tag1U2ViewController *ivc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"uebung2"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:ivc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but just in case it helps else my problem was that the xib file somehow got removed from the target project so it's worth double checking on that through Target Membership. It's possible a bad merge could've caused it.